# jQuery returning null - selected option not being posted correctly?

Tags: ajax, jquery

This jQuery script is returning null. I've tried using other syntax for selected options but here's what I've got below:

The script works and runs correctly, allowing me to download the Excel file. However the ID is not being set correctly (via the option selected) and thus is parsing as "0".

```
<script>
//When Page Loads....
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#dropdown').change(function(){
    // Call the function to handle the AJAX.
    // Pass the value of the text box to the function.
    sendValue($(this).val());   
  }); 
});

// Function to handle ajax.
function sendValue(str){
  // post(file, data, callback, type); (only "file" is required)
  $.post(
    "scripts/export_to_excel/index.php", //Ajax file
    { sendValue: str },  // create an object will all values
    //function that is called when server returns a value.
    function(data){
      $('#linkDiv').html(data.returnValue);
    }, 
    //How you want the data formatted when it is returned from the server.
    "json"
  );
}
</script>
```

Select HTML

```
<p>Select event for export to Excel:</p>
<p>
  <select name="eventIDExport" id="dropdown"> 
    <option value=0> 
    <?=$options?> 
  </select>
</p>
<?php var_dump($_POST['eventIDExport']); ?>
<div id="linkDiv"></div>
```

Rendered mark-up

```
<p>Select event for export to Excel:</p>
<p>
  <select name="eventIDExport" id="dropdown"> 
    <option value=0> 
    <option value="1">BIG event</option>
    <option value="54">2013 Network Conference</option>
  </select>
</p>
NULL
<div id="linkDiv"></div>
```

Some of the code in index.php to process Ajax request - I think this is triggering the null value?

```
if (isset($_POST['eventIDExport']))
{
$eventIDExport = $_POST['eventIDExport'];
}else{
$eventIDExport = "";    
}
```

Comment: <option value=0> ... what's this?

Comment: That's the default option, if it's not selected it shouldn't be posted?

Comment: @PhilHudson can you post the rendered markup instead of php codes?

Comment: @PhilHudson yes but where is it escaped? </option>?

Comment: @DavidBarker thanks for your suggestion. I've just escaped it and it didn't impact the value. It is still "0". Thanks

Comment: Really can't get this to break, tested with an alert instead of an ajax call and the value is coming through fine: http://jsfiddle.net/WKNhV/

Comment: this works here http://jsfiddle.net/wzZEq/

Comment: Either way your markup will be better off for it :) Just as a pointer. Add a `console.log($(this).val());` to your .change function. Take a look to see if it is actually sending the right data to the ajax function. If it is, your problem is with your PHP script.

Comment: Thanks Andy, in that case, could it be a server side problem?

Comment: @AndyRose in my Ajax file, I use the following: `if (isset($_POST['eventIDExport']))
 {
 $eventIDExport = $_POST['eventIDExport'];
}else{
 $eventIDExport = "1"; 
 }` I've set it to one and it exported the event ID 1, so it does appear that it's not posting properly.

Comment: It's definitely not posting correctly. @DavidBarker I'm still unsure as to why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you POST `sendValue` and check if `eventIDExport` is set?

```
$.post("scripts/export_to_excel/index.php", {
    sendValue: str
    ^^^^^^^^^
```

and

```
if (isset($_POST['eventIDExport']))
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Your code should be:

```
if(isset($_POST['sendValue']))
{
    $eventIDExport = $_POST['sendValue'];
} else {
    $eventIDExport = "";
}
```

or

```
$.post("scripts/export_to_excel/index.php", {
    eventIDExport: str
```

Comment: Thank you so much, a late night of coding has taken its toll on mee! Very much appreciated!